# PHP Websocket server subscribe for redis

Tags: php, websocket, redis, predis

it's my first question. :)
So my problem is that:
I have a Apache server, who use Redis(Predis) server. Also have and WebSocket server ([PHP WebSocketServer](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets), who need to "subscribe" Redis server.
For subscribing I use:

```
    $pubsub = $client->pubSubLoop();
// Subscribe to your channels
$pubsub->subscribe('control_channel', 'notifications');
// Start processing the pubsup messages. Open a terminal and use redis-cli
// to push messages to the channels. Examples:
//   ./redis-cli PUBLISH notifications "this is a test"
//   ./redis-cli PUBLISH control_channel quit_loop
foreach ($pubsub as $message) {
    switch ($message->kind) {
        case 'subscribe':
            echo "Subscribed to {$message->channel}", PHP_EOL;
            break;
        case 'message':
            if ($message->channel == 'control_channel') {
                if ($message->payload == 'quit_loop') {
                    echo "Aborting pubsub loop...", PHP_EOL;
                    $pubsub->unsubscribe();
                } else {
                    echo "Received an unrecognized command: {$message->payload}.", PHP_EOL;
                }
            } else {
                echo "Received the following message from {$message->channel}:",
                     PHP_EOL, "  {$message->payload}", PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I realize that the WebSocket server using kind of infinite loop, and Predis (subscribe) is the same.

So hit me if I'm wrong, or can you give me some advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this, I am facing the same issue